# jQuery fadeOut and fadeIn seemingly not consistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Inside of an html table I have a button that performs an update (the update functionality is removed because it doesn't matter). Upon completion of the update, a bootstrap label is shown and then hidden to show the update was completed. I am using jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to show/hide the label.

I would like the label to be aligned with the top of the button. I thought I had it working correctly, but, I noticed that the label is **only aligned correctly the first time I click the update button**. Strangely, after the first time, the label appears below the button.

[Demonstration Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9wfmuLr/2/)

I don't see how/why this is happening. Why doesn't the updated label appear to the right of the button every time?

UPDATE:

Interestingly, changing this line `$("#updatedLabel").fadeOut(300);`  to `$("#updatedLabel").css('display', 'none');` fixes the problem, though it is less pretty.

Answer (score 0):

This is because JQuery's `fadeIn` function changes the display to "block" when you want "inline-block".

Instead, change your style to be:

```
<span id="updatedLabel" class="label label-success" style="display:inline-block; opacity: 0;">Updated!</span>
```

And then use `animate` to change opacity:

```
 //Put this inside an interval
 opacity -= 10;
 if ( opacity <= 0 ) clearInterval( interval );
 $( "#updatedLabel" ).animate({opacity: opacity });
```